# populate doesn't work for Mongoose always return undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create an e-learning app and this is my schemas, but the problem right now whenever i try to render user's courses in mongodb and it shows courses that a specific user is having.

The data is in the array

```
"courses" : [ "Learn how to be awesome", "Learn how to be a chef" ]
```

Two Schemas

```
var UserSchema = Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
  courses: [{ type: Schema.Types.String, ref: 'Course'}],
});

var CourseSchema = Schema({
  title: String,
  owners: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
  body: String,
  teacher: { type: Schema.Types.String, ref: 'User'},

});
```

routes.js - whenever i try to populate a user's courses object, it always return undefined

```
router.get('/my-courses', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {

  User
    .findById(req.user.id)
    .populate('courses')
    .exec(function(err, courses) {
      console.log(courses); // always return undefined
      res.render('course/student-courses', {
        userCourses: courses
      });
    });
});
```

It always return an undefined even though I already added the data into the user's courses field.

Comment: Populate only works on the `_id` value of the referenced model, but it looks like you're using the `title` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should change your UserSchema:

```
var UserSchema = Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
  courses: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Course'}],
});
```

You can reference another schema only by _id. 
Also do this change for teacher inside CourseSchema.

Then use populate with field selection:

```
  User
    .findById(req.user.id)
    .populate('courses', 'title')
    .exec(function(err, courses) {
      console.log(courses); // always return undefined
      res.render('course/student-courses', {
        userCourses: courses
      });
    });
```

It will return only title of courses.